# Finding half a diagonal in a rhombus using trigonometric ratios?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So, if you take a rhombus, then call the bottom left hand corner $A$, the top left hand corner $B$, the top right hand corner $C$, and the bottom right hand corner $D$. Then draw the two diagonals.

The angle of the bottom left hand corner is $60°$. The side lengths are $10$ cm. Call the point where the diagonals bisect each other $X$. I have to find the distance of $AX$.

Comment: Do you know that the diagonals a rhombus bisect vertex angles and are perpendicular to each other?

Answer (score 1):

When you are facing a geometry problem you have no idea how to proceed, it is usually useful to draw an accurate picture on paper/computer and look for hints.

I use [GeoGebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoGebra) to generate the picture at end. As you can see, the line BD and AC looks perpendicular to each other. You can look up facts/theorem about rhombus and indeed it
is the case. Since triangle $\triangle AXD$ is a right angled triangle and
$\measuredangle DAX = \frac12 \measuredangle DAB = 30^{\circ}$, one get:

$$|AX| = |AD| \cos 30^{\circ} = 10 (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = 5 \sqrt{3}$$.

[image: A rhombus]